# Understanding what the solution for Leetcode 621. Task Scheduler Question

Tags: python, math, computer-science

Hi everyone I have a question about the leet code question 621 solution:

Given a characters array tasks, representing the tasks a CPU needs to do, where each letter represents a different task. Tasks could be done in any order. Each task is done in one unit of time. For each unit of time, the CPU could complete either one task or just be idle.

However, there is a non-negative integer n that represents the cooldown period between two same tasks (the same letter in the array), that is that there must be at least n units of time between any two same tasks.

Return the least number of units of times that the CPU will take to finish all the given tasks.

The solution is below. Here at the end we return idle time + len(tasks). If all of our tasks get filled up in the idle times I understand we return len(tasks) but lets say that we have filled up all of our idle times, and we have a bunch of tasks remaining. Why does len(tasks) guarantee that we will be able to process the remaining tasks given our cool down period.

For example, lets say our input is AAAABBBCC and cool period is1. According to this algorithm, we will have 3 idle spots initially: A_A_A_A where _ is an idle spot. So we will have frequencies as [2,3] for 2 for C and 3 for B respectively . Initially we will put the three Bs in the idle spots so we get ABABABA now we have two Cs left. How does it work with the Cs at the end given we have cool down period of 1.

```
def leastInterval(self, tasks: List[str], n: int) -> int:
        # frequencies of the tasks
        frequencies = [0] * 26
        for t in tasks:
            frequencies[ord(t) - ord('A')] += 1
        
        frequencies.sort()

        # max frequency
        f_max = frequencies.pop()
        idle_time = (f_max - 1) * n
        
        while frequencies and idle_time > 0:
            idle_time -= min(f_max - 1, frequencies.pop())
        idle_time = max(0, idle_time)

        return idle_time + len(tasks)
```

Comment: Can you provide a case where this doesn't work as expected? What would be your implementation for it that works as expected? Please also pick a title that conveys a bit of context on the problem itself (not just where you found it) and add a language tag.

Comment: got it I hope its structured better now.

Comment: At least in the example you gave, I could run ABACABACB.   If I were writing a greedy algorithm, I'd take the letter that has the most left that isn't the same as the last element.  And the letter that has the most left changes as the algorithm runs.